# divs changing position on resizing

Tags: css, layout, window-resize

Right floated div shift below the left floated div in the same containing div when i re-size the browser window smaller. everything appears normal until i re size window.

where c1 is the parent and c1a is the left div, while c1b is the right div.

```
#c1 {
    margin-top: 50px;

}
#c1a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 30px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
}

#c1b {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    width: 180px;
    font-size: x-small;
    background-color: #CCC;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 200px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    padding-left: 12px;
}
```

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The right div will fall to the next line if it overlaps the left div when you resize the outer container.  Couple things u can do..set a width on the parent so that it doesn't resize or set a min-width to prevent it from shrinking below a certain size.

Answer (score 0):

Set the min-width of your parent div greater than the total width and margins of your child divs.

Answer (score 0):

when the base of a building is strong, rooms are also strong. You are trying to build a house on water. Make your base container strong by giving its width.

Answer (score 0):

Give your #c1 div a min-width of 440px - here's a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/G6HUy/